# Disable Gamepad navigation in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, gamepad

I have an UWP screen that reads and proccess gamepad data/readings. It was doing fine untill today.
The gamepad started to control button highlights and navigation (pressing A to confirm).
Is there any way of disabling the gamepad navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution!

If you're having the same issue, modify the 'IsTabStop' property to false.

```
<Button IsTabStop="False" />
```

The gamepad works like pressing tabs on the keyboard, by disabling the TabStop the program will ignore that element when a tab is pressed.